# How to make a foreign key within two columns is the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I have a database called `laravelpro` and in it there is a table called `categories`.
Here is the migration that makes the `categories` table.

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();

  $table->string('name');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent')->default(0);
  $table->foreign('parent')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->timestamps();
});
```

In `categories` table, a category can be another category's parent(I'm doing this with the `parent` field).
As you can see there is a line in migration that is making a foreign key from the `parent` field to the `id` field.
The purpose of doing this action is that I want to remove all subcategories of a category after I remove the parent category and so on ...
I ran the migration with no errors but when I want to add a category, I will face his error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails 
(`laravelpro`.`categories`, CONSTRAINT `categories_parent_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE)
INSERT INTO `categories` (`name`, `parent`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) VALUES (test, 0, 2022-10-06 20:33:41, 2022-10-06 20:33:41)
```

I searched a lot and didn't find anything related to my subject.
Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: `parent` can't have a value of `0` since there is no matching record with 'id' of `0` (the autoincrement will start at `1`)... you would want to make the field "nullable" and set the `parent` to `null` if there is no parent

Comment: Thanks. that just do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make parent nullable.

```
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->id();

  $table->string('name');
  $table->unsignedBigInteger('parent')->nullable();
  $table->foreign('parent')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');

  $table->timestamps();
});
```